# Why does ï»¿ appear in my data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I downloaded the file 'pi_million_digits.txt' from here:

https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/blob/master/chapter_10/pi_million_digits.txt

I then used this code to open and read it:

```
filename = 'pi_million_digits.txt'

with open(filename) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()

pi_string = ''
for line in lines:
    pi_string += line.strip()

print(pi_string[:52] + "...")
print(len(pi_string))
```

However the output produced is correct apart from the fact it is preceded by same strange symbols: "ï»¿3.141...."

What causes these strange symbols? I am stripping the lines so I'd expect such symbols to be removed.

Comment: The file is likely corrupted.

Comment: I have looked at the file in a text editor and it looks OK? Could it look OK in the text editor and still be corrupted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you're opening a file with a UTF-8 encoded [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) using the ISO-8859-1 encoding (presumably because this is the default encoding on your OS).

If you open it as bytes and read the first line, you should see something like this:

```
>>> next(open('pi_million_digits.txt', 'rb'))
b'\xef\xbb\xbf3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679\n'
```

… where `\xef\xbb\xbf` is the UTF-8 encoding of the BOM. Opened as ISO-8859-1, it looks like what you're getting:

```
>>> next(open('pi_million_digits.txt', encoding='iso-8859-1'))
'ï»¿3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679\n'
```

… and opening it as UTF-8 shows the actual BOM character U+FEFF:

```
>>> next(open('pi_million_digits.txt', encoding='utf-8'))
'\ufeff3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679\n'
```

To strip the mark out, use the special encoding `utf-8-sig`:

```
>>> next(open('pi_million_digits.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig'))
'3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679\n'
```

The use of `next()` in the examples above is just for demonstration purposes. In your code, you just need to add the `encoding` argument to your `open()` line, e.g.

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8-sig') as file_object:
    # ... etc.
```